# Intel C compiler catastrophic error: cannot open source file "stdio.h" MacOS

Tags: macos-catalina, stdio, icc, intel-parallel-studio

I installed Intel parallel studio XE on my Macbook running MacOS Catalina 10.15.
The Intel C and C++ compilers refuse to work and throw following error.

> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/stdio.h(107): catastrophic error: cannot open source file "stdio.h"
>
> `#include_next <stdio.h>`

The `stdio.h` file exists and my other clang and gcc compilers are working great.

Absolutely any inputs would be really helpful! Thanks in advance